# Changing image src with jQuery. (Doesn't work on Firefox)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, captcha, explorer

I'm writing an Ajax contact form. I have written my own captcha too. But I have a problem about refreshing the image. I have written this like that:

Reloading the captcha:

```
<code>$("#captchaSection").load("captcha_p.php");</code>
```

And the captcha_p.php file:

```
<code>< img src="captcha.php" name="imgCaptcha" /></code>
```

And I have added this lines to the capcha.php:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

It works perfect on Google Chrome and Safari. But doesn't work on Firefox and Explorer.

Thanks!

Comment: where is id=captchaSection?

Comment: Hello @TusharGupta No, on 127.0.0.1 :)

Comment: @xlordt hello. captchaSection is a div.

Comment: Hello, you need to post that here as well. Also you can just change the src of the image something like (#captchaSection).attr ("src")= image. You can also recreate the image.

Comment: Oh, I've tryed that and captchaIMG.src="captcha.php"; and many more, Getting the same result ... thanks @xlordt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that Firefox and IE are caching the image. To prevent this, append a timestamp to the URL and image source:

In Javascript you can use `new Date().getTime()`:

```
$("#captchaSection").load("captcha_p.php?" + new Date().getTime());
```

In PHP you can use `microtime()`:

```
< img src="captcha.php?<?php echo microtime(); ?>" name="imgCaptcha" />
```

I don't see any benefit of using `.load()` to load HTML that contains the image. It would be easier to just change the `src` property of the image, for example:

```
// refresh captcha
$('img[name=imgCaptcha]').prop('src', 'captcha.php?' + new Date().getTime());
```

Comment: using timestamp to ensure that what you're requesting is a new thing is a great idea!